# What does += do for list in Scala?

Tags: list, scala, append, prepend

What does the  += do here ? Does it mean append to the list?
If maxNodes = 16, Do the below lines mean that values 0 to 15 are stored in NodeList? Or is it 0 to 16?

```
var Nodelist = new ArrayBuffer[Int]()
for (i <- 0 until maxNodes) {     
          Nodelist += i  
 }
```

Comment: Why are you asking here? What happens when **you** try it? Are you getting any errors? Are you not getting the results you expect? Do you not _understand_ the results you're getting?

Comment: @AlonsodelArte `ArrayBuffer` is mutable.

Comment: Btw that is not a **List** is an **ArrayBuffer**, two very different things that you shouldn't mix their names.

Comment: @Ava Oops, that was a gaffe on my part, I meant to write "mutable."

Comment: What I should've written yesterday: "Using a mutable collection like `ArrayBuffer` in this manner is not very idiomatic Scala. It would be much easier to write something like `var nodeList = 0 until maxNodes`. See https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Msf7oARWTOCFuW7prsxaeA " As @Ava pointed out, I goofed by a couple of extra syllables. Other than that, I stand by what I wrote.

Comment: Anyone care to give me any grief over the term "Javadoc" in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just appending the `Integer` value in variable `i` to the list.  Why not try this in the REPL?

Answer (score 1):

[According to the Javadoc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayBuffer.html), `+=` in `ArrayBuffer` is an "alias" for `addOne()`. So at the beginning `NodeList` is empty (I'd rather call it `nodeList`). On the first go at the For loop, the integer 0 is added to `NodeList`. On the next go around, the integer 1 will be added to `NodeList`, and so and so forth. Since you used `until` rather than `to`, the iteration will stop one short of `maxNodes`.